# How do I execute this python code automatically in in excel cells?

Tags: python, excel, split

I need to extract the domain for example: (http: //www.example.com/example-page, http ://test.com/test-page) from a list of websites in an excel sheet and modify that domain to give its url (example.com, test.com). I have got the code part figured put but i still need to get these commands to work on excel sheet cells in a column automatically.

here's_the_code[image]

Comment: You can Look at `OpenPyxl` library to work with excel files in Python. You can write all text directly to the Excel cells using that library. [Link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2745495). Post them as **text** because they are text. Please see the **Code Blocks** section of the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read in the data as a pandas DataFrame (pd.read_excel), make a function from your code then apply to the dframe (df.apply). Then it is easy to save to excel with pd.to_excel().

ofc you will need pandas to be installed. 
Something like:

```
    import pandas as pd
    dframe = pd.read_excel(io='' , sheet_name='')
    dframe['domains'] = dframe['urls col name'].apply(your function)
    dframe.to_excel('your path')
```

Best